# How to remove splash screen / logos when the game starts

Tags: kingdom-come-deliverance

Anyone managed to find out how to remove or skip the ads when the game starts?

Answer (score 2):

The main splash screens showing the Warhorse logo can't be skipped yet. You can only skip the intro about the backstory with <kbd>Esc</kbd>. I imagine we will find a way to remove the file or mod it out in time.