# How to skip the intro / splash screen at the start of Kingdom Come: Deliverance

Tags: ps4, kingdom-come-deliverance

I'm playing Kingdom Come: Deliverance on the PS4, but each time the game starts, it 'introduces' us to the history of the time period the game is set in while loading the menu. It's just 2 minutes, but I'd prefer to skip this if possible, as I don't even spend a second on the menu to continue my game, so it's kind of absurd to wait for 2 minutes listing to the same thing over and over.

Related, but for the PC only: [How to remove splash screen / logos when the game starts](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/326766/205568)

**EDIT:** This is for the PS4, so is not a duplicate of [How to remove splash screen / logos when the game starts](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/326766/205568)

Comment: The linked question is not limited to PC. Just because it has no answer for PS4 yet doesn't mean a new question needs to be asked.

Comment: Which keys have you tried pressing on the PS4 controller?  If Esc skips the intro on PC, I would expect *some button* does the same on consoles.

Comment: I've tried all the buttons apart from 'Share' and 'Home', as they are only used by the PS4

Comment: Reopening as the linked question doesn't actually answer this one. We ran an experiment on this in 2016 and the result was to err on the side of leaving these "borderline" duplicates open.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to wait during the intro for just the main menu to load but the entire game and your save states. Sadly there isn't an option to get out of the logos/intro for the PS4 yet and I have not heard about this subject being touched for the next patch.

Comment: At first, I thought that as well, but when you 'Continue' or 'Load' your saves, it takes some time to load them, so I'm pretty sure the game isn't actually loading during the opening, but the main menu only.

Comment: Yeah that's true. If it needs to read every 2GB pack then it might take a while. However I do doubt that the long intro is only for the loading screen. That is usually the longest load. I think it still pre loads some things that are always constant such as day night cycles, vegetations, spawn rates, and conversations. I'd love to get an answer to this also

Answer (score -3):

Hold square for a few seconds that skips